# Conditions under which an adult grandchild of a Spanish citizen can acquire Spanish citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, spain

Does the adult British and born in Britain grandchild of a Spanish citizen have a right to Spanish citizenship? And if not, are they treated the same as a person who has no Spanish connections?

I have read [this page](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Pages/Nacionalidad.aspx) published by Spain's London consulate, and the answer seems to turn on the meaning of the statement that having been born to a "Spanish" parent determines that a person is considered to be of "Spanish origin". It may be that when a person who was born in Spain and is a Spanish citizen becomes a parent outside of Spain their child is not only considered to be "of Spanish origin" but also "Spanish" in that they can pass Spanish citizenship on to their own offspring even if they themselves never get a Spanish passport or ever visit Spain.

Or it may be that this is not so and that what would be available to the grandchild is only "nationality by residence", but which they would be entitled to acquire after one year of residence in Spain rather than 10 years.

Note: user @27096 believes the fact that the person's parent and their Spanish grandparent are deceased may be relevant.

Comment: Yes, via father, or mother, or parental authority of the _spanish national_ grandparent.

Comment: Thanks for this. But please can you define what you mean by "via", "authority", and "spanish national". The parent (who did not claim Spanish citizenship but presumably had a right to) and grandfather (a Spanish citizen - or more exactly, a Spanish subject, born in Spain before 1931) are both deceased.

Comment: I afraid death of all spanish relatives is an important note should be written up at the question :(

Comment: @27096 - Note added.

Comment: The parent may have been a Spanish citizen without having claimed Spanish citizenship.

Comment: Yes indeed. The parent seems to classify as "of Spanish origin", not loosely but in some kind of official meaning, having been born to a Spanish parent, although I'm not sure what the meaning is because I read the consulate's material in English and know little about Spanish law - hence the question.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter whether they classify as "of Spanish origin" or not; only whether they classify as Spanish nationals or not. Better ask the Spanish government.